# In how far is a SharePoint page linked to an Office 365 group? Advantages and disadvantages, what to consider?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, office-365-groups, business

I ask this because we are faced with the question of whether different business areas (dev, support) should be subdivided into different website collections, or whether it makes sense to have a general website collection (product XY wiki) under which the business areas are represented in subsites.

What are the advantages and disadvantages regarding Office 365 groups (permissions, functions, etc.) and what should be considered and observed in advance?

A few questions that came to my mind spontaneously:

- What are the benefits of linking SharePoint and an Office 365 group?
- This link happens automatically when a new SharePoint page is created, right?
- This link happens only on the top level (website collection) and not for subsites etc.?

I just want to get some clarity. I have already read the Microsoft help pages extensively and unfortunately they do not help me.